How can I split a Sum in SymPy?
SymPy understands that Sum and + commute.
from sympy import symbols, Idx, IndexedBase, Sum

i, n = symbols("i n", cls=Idx)
x = IndexedBase("x", shape=(n,))
s = Sum(x[i] + 1, (i, 1, n))
t = Sum(x[i], (i, 1, n)) + Sum(1, (i, 1, n))
assert s.equals(t)  # OK

But for complex expressions that does not work.
from sympy import symbols, Idx, IndexedBase, Sum

a, b = symbols("a b")
i, n = symbols("i n", cls=Idx)
w = IndexedBase("w", shape=(n,))
x = IndexedBase("x", shape=(n,))
y = IndexedBase("y", shape=(n,))
sum = lambda e: Sum(e, (i, 1, n))
sw = sum(w[i])
mx = sum(w[i] * x[i]) / sw
my = sum(w[i] * y[i]) / sw
d = w[i] * ((a * (x[i] - mx) - (y[i] - my)))**2
e = w[i] * (a * mx + b - my)**2
f = w[i] * 2 * (a * (x[i] - mx) - (y[i] - my)) * (a * mx + b - my)
s = sum(d + e + f)
t = sum(d) + sum(e) + sum(f)
assert s.equals(t)  # The assert fails

How can we explain to SymPy that this transformation is actually OK?

It is difficult to give a good answer if you don't provide runnable code demonstrating the problem. You also haven't explained what "Fail" means: what does s.equals(t) return?

Edited the assert failure comment. equals compares 2 expressions.

Does it work if d, e, f are simple expressions? You may have simply run into something too complex for sympy to analyze.

@user24714692 Before the edit there was a comment # d, e, f = 3 rather large expressions. So they were defined, the OP just omitted the definitions for brevity. They've since added the definitions.

You can use expand() and simplify():
from sympy import symbols, Idx, IndexedBase, Sum, expand, simplify

a, b = symbols("a b")
i, n = symbols("i n", cls=Idx)
w = IndexedBase("w", shape=(n,))
x = IndexedBase("x", shape=(n,))
y = IndexedBase("y", shape=(n,))
sum = lambda e: Sum(e, (i, 1, n))
sw = sum(w[i])
mx = sum(w[i] * x[i]) / sw
my = sum(w[i] * y[i]) / sw
d = w[i] * ((a * (x[i] - mx) - (y[i] - my)))**2
e = w[i] * (a * mx + b - my)**2
f = w[i] * 2 * (a * (x[i] - mx) - (y[i] - my)) * (a * mx + b - my)
s = sum(d + e + f)
t = sum(d) + sum(e) + sum(f)

se, te = expand(s), expand(t)
ss, ts = simplify(se), simplify(te)

print(ss.equals(ts))


Prints
True
Note form comment (@smichr):
SymPy favors not doing automatic simplification, so it is appropriate to expect to do some to show that expressions are the same. If equals were modified to do expansion, this might have worked for you, but it only does diff = factor_terms(simplify(self - other), radical=True) at the outset.

SymPy favors not doing automatic simplification, so it is appropriate to expect to do some to show that expressions are the same. If equals were modified to do expansion, this might have worked for you, but it only does diff = factor_terms(simplify(self - other), radical=True) at the outset.

@smichr I'd love to help SymPy understand the structure of the equation, but how?

As the answer suggested, use expand, maybe like this: expand(s-t).equals(0) -> True?
